# Wiener process clarification

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

It is not clear to me exactly what the Wiener process is. I know the theory, I just don't know if 
$dW(t) = \epsilon \sqrt(dt)$ where $\epsilon \sim N(0,1)$ and so $dW(t) \sim N(0, d t)$ is the Wiener process or $W(t) = \int_0^t dW(\tau)$ is the Wiener process.

My understanding is that $W(t)$ is the Wiener process and $d W(t)$ is called the differential of the Wiener process.

Comment: $W(t)$ is the Wiener process.

Comment: Did you read a formal definition?

Comment: Yes, I did - a book and a set of lecture notes. I think I might have read too many sources which became confusing at the end.

Comment: your expression $\int_0^{t} 1dW(\tau)$ is a Wiener integral that has as result $W(t)$ (the Wiener process); but it's not the definition!

Comment: I see nothing from any definition here.